# Change original array by another array in java

Tags: java

I created simple insertion method to insert value to array. But i want to need some way to change my original array after using that method. For example my array has 5 numbers. After using that inserting method i need to change it having 6 numbers.

```
public class inserting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[]={5,3,1,6,7};
        insert(0,10,a);
        //i need to change my array like this = [10, 5, 3, 1, 6, 7] after apply insert method
    }
    static void insert(int pos, int val, int arr[]){
        int newArr[]=new int[(arr.length)+1];
        for(int i=arr.length; i>pos; i--){
            newArr[i]=arr[i-1];
        }
        newArr[pos]=val;
        for(int i=0; i<pos; i++){
            newArr[i]=arr[i];
        }
       
        
    }
}
```

i need to change my `a` array like this = [10, 5, 3, 1, 6, 7] after apply inserting method

Comment: Have the `insert` function `return` the new array and change to `a = insert(0,10,a);`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the way you did it.  Just return the new array as the return type.  But you may want to check out the methods in:

[Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html)
[System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int))

They have several methods to help copy values.

Here is an example of using the latter.

```
static int[] insert(int pos, int val, int arr[]){
    int newArr[]=new int[(arr.length)+1];
    System.arraycopy(arr,0,newArr, 0, pos);
    newArr[pos] = val;
    System.arraycopy(arr, pos, newArr,pos+1,arr.length-pos);
    return newArr;
}
```